# Android Wear: DataItem sent to Wearable also received by local Binding - how to prevent this?

Tags: android

I have a question regarding Android Wear: `Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem`:

My App sends some data from the mobile to the wear by using:

```
dataToWearRequest = PutDataRequest.create("/image");
dataToWearRequest.setData(compressedPictureAsByteArray);
Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, dataToWearRequest);
```

The wear is receiving the data correctly by using an activity which implements `DataApi.DataListener`:

```
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
    for (DataEvent event : dataEvents) {
        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED &&
                event.getDataItem().getUri().getPath().equals("/image")) {
            DataItem dataItem = event.getDataItem();
            byte content[] = dataItem.getData();
            if (mDebug) System.out.println("onDataChanged: receiver: content.length="+ content.length);
        }
    }
}
```

But my mobile app has also a `WearableListenerService` which is desired to receive messages from the wear. The `WearableListenerService` class itself also implements  the `DataApi.DataListener` (as I said: on the mobile). In this Service the `onDataChanged` method also receives the data packet which was sent to the wear. It is implemented very simple (in my case because I dont need data packets from the wear):

```
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
    //super.onDataChanged(dataEvents);
    for (DataEvent event : dataEvents) {
        System.out.println("WEAR Data changed: "+event.getDataItem().getUri().toString());
    }
    dataEvents.close();
}
```

The corresponding manifest entry for this mobile service looks as usual:

```
<service android:name=".RemoteControlWearService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I have tried to set an intent-filter in the manifest file of the mobile with an unknown path just to prevent it from receiving the /image data. But that did not help.

I am asking the question because the mobile indeed duplicates the data packet sent to the wear to be able to call `onDataReceived`. Inside the `Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem` seems to be a memory leak: when you send many images to the wear the memory consumption of the mobile is increasing and never garbage collected (that are native buffers). I want to reduce the memory consumption of the mobile app by preventing the sending of the unneeded parcel to the local service.

Does anybody knows how I could prevent my local mobile service from receiving the data packet directed to the wear only?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the local node id [see here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/NodeApi.html#getLocalNode(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)), then compare it to the one that triggered the `DataEvent` by calling `dataItem.getUri().getHost()`. The best way to compare would be by calling `equals()`on the value returned by `dataItem.getUri().getHost()` and put the localNodeId as parameter.

You can see my implementation below:

```
@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
    String localNodeId = NodeUtils.getLocalNodeId(this);
    for (DataEvent dataEvent : dataEvents) {
        if (dataEvent.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
            DataItem dataItem = dataEvent.getDataItem();
            String host = dataItem.getUri().getHost();
            if (host.equals(localNodeId)) continue; // Ignore local changes
            if (dataItem.getUri().getPath().equals(THE_DATA_PATH_I_WANT)) {
                DataMap dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(dataItem).getDataMap();
                // Do something with my DataMap
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with the code used to get the node id

```
public class NodeUtils {

@Nullable
public static String getLocalNodeId(@NonNull Context context) {
    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
    ConnectionResult connectionResult = googleApiClient.blockingConnect(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return connectionResult.isSuccess() ? getLocalNodeId(googleApiClient) : null;
}

@Nullable
public static String getLocalNodeId(@NonNull GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
    NodeApi.GetLocalNodeResult nodeResult =
            Wearable.NodeApi.getLocalNode(googleApiClient).await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (nodeResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        return nodeResult.getNode().getId();
    } else {
        Timber.wtf("couldn't get local node? status: %s", nodeResult.getStatus());
        return null;
    }
}
```

}